# Should we traverse map? Why?

Tags: java, dictionary, foreach, set

If we are using map,I think there is no need for traverse object by for each loop or other way. We have a unique key and value so we can easily find value.
I faced this question so many time in interview. I don't think so this question is 
correct. Please help me in regarding question.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking - do you want reasons why it is sometimes (quite often, actually) necessary to iterate over all entries in  a Map?

Comment: Simply Map has a Directory Structure. Just put a Key and find Value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should traverse a map when ... you need to traverse a map. You're correct that if you have a key, you don't need to do any traversal; just use the key. But there are times you don't have a key. For instance, imagine a map keyed by people's names with their ages as values:

```
Map<String, Integer> m = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
// Presumably these are added by a user or similar
m.put("Joe", 27);
m.put("Mohammad", 42);
m.put("Maria", 29);
```

Later we need to output all the names and ages; we'll traverse the map (more technically, we'll traverse its entry set):

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : m.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(e.getKey() + ": " + e.getValue());
}
```

Other times we might traverse `keySet` or `values`.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to iterate all entries in a Map whenever you want to do something to/with all Entries.

Common things that you often want to do with entries:

- Print/display all of them
- Filter them to get a new Map with certain properties
- Search for an item with specific properties
- Calculate statistics of the values in the Map (sum, max, min, average)